# How to select a first record checkbox among multiple records in a grid?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have tried below

```
IWebElement selectchk = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox' and starts-with(@id,'ctl00_UserContentArea_rgBulkSFA_ctl00_')]"));
```

but the problem is all the check-boxes in the grid have the same starts with Id, hence all the check-boxes are getting selected. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath, it will give only the first element of the list:
`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//input[@type='checkbox' and starts-with(@id,'ctl00_UserContentArea_rgBulkSFA_ctl00_')])[1]"));`